# Prove that $e^n n! \geq n^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

I want to prove that
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
e^n n! \geq n^n,\: \forall \: n \in \mathbb{N^*}. 
\end{equation}

We will proceed by induction. For n=1 is true.

Suppose valid for some  $n \in \mathbb{N^*}$.

We will prove that it is valid for $n+1$. Equivalently, we will prove that
$$
(n+1)+\ln((n+1)!) \geq (n+1) \ln(n+1).$$
Indeed,

\begin{eqnarray}
(n+1)+\ln((n+1)!)& = & (n+1)+\ln((n+1)n!)\\
& = & n+1+\ln(n+1)+\ln n! \\
& \geq & n \ln n+1+\ln(n+1).
\end{eqnarray}

I thought to write $ \ln n = \int_{1} ^ {n} \frac{1}{x}\;dx $.But I couldn't get out of that last line. How to continue? Or is that not the way?

Comment: $\Bbb N^*$? Is that supposed to be $\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$?

Comment: Finish with a second induction by proving $n\ln n + 1 \ge n\ln(n+1)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use induction; one can observe that

$e^n = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^j}{j!}$

Thus $e^n n! = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^jn!}{j!} \geq \frac{n^nn!}{n!} = n^n$

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler rearrangement with induction:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le e\implies\frac{n^n}{n!}\le e^n$$